# How to set `aria-selected=true` via jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, wai-aria

How can I change the state of `aria-selected="false"` to `aria-selected="true"` by using jQuery?

Here you can see how I tried to do it:

```
$('element aria-selected').html(true)
$('element aria-selected').text(true)
$('element aria-selected').val(true)
$('element').attr('aria-selected', 'true').prop('selected', true)
$('element').attr('aria-selected', 'true')
$('element').prop('selected', true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `prop()` or `attr()` can set `aria-selected` attribute to `true`

Correct code is :

`$('element').prop('aria-selected', true);`

or

`$('element').attr('aria-selected', true);`

**More detailed information about each property :**

If element is container like `div`, `p`, `h1`, `b`, `a` etc you need to use `html()`
The html() method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements.

- `$('element aria-selected').html(true)`

So `html()` will not work here.

If element is container like `div`, `p`, `h1`, `b`, `a`, etc you need to use `text()`
Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML documents. The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

- `$('element aria-selected').text(true)`

So `text()` will not work here.

If element is input field like text, hidden etc you need to use `val()`

- `$('element aria-selected').val(true)`

So `val()` will not work here.

The prop() method sets or returns properties and values of the selected elements.
The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set. It returns undefined for the value of a property that has not been set

- `$('element').attr('aria-selected', 'true').prop('selected', true)`
- `$('element').prop('selected', true)`

The attr() method sets or returns attributes and values of the selected elements.

- `$('element').attr('aria-selected', 'true')`

So `attr()` will work here.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('element').attr('aria-selected',true);
```

This will solve your purpose

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JavaScript code to resolve:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("yourSelector");
elem.setAttribute('aria-selected', false); //If attribute is true, and false needed
elem.setAttribute('aria-selected', true); //If attribute is false, and true needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution will work with jQuery:

```
$('element').prop('ariaSelected', false);
$('element').prop('ariaSelected', true);
```